# DataContext and Binding not working in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I am a wpf-er first time work on UWP. I've found DataContext in VM and Binding in ResourceDictionary is not working in UWP:

first I create a Model:

```
public class PersonModel :BindableBase
{
    private string _name = string.Empty;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); } }
}
```

then I put this model in MainPage.cs :

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Person.Name = "Oh My Dog";       
    }

    public PersonModel Person { get; } = new PersonModel();
}
```

I create a style for ContentControl in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <!-- Person -->
        <Style x:Key="PersonStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

then put a ContentControl in MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource PersonStyle}" DataContext="{Binding Person}"/>
</Grid>
```

But it not working, nothing displayed on MainPage.xaml.

So is it because UWP not support DataContext? need a correct example for my case, thanks!

Comment: This would also not work in WPF. What makes you think `DataContext="{Binding Person}"` would magically use the MainPage instance as source object of the Binding?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

in your MainPage.xaml.cs constructor:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Person = new PersonModel("Oh My Dog");
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

I think it would be the same for WPF either, so it's not special to UWP.